# Snackbar in a transparent activity

Tags: android, themes, transparency, android-snackbar

Was trying to make a snackbar in a transparent `Activity` and got errors, changed the theme in `Manifest` to  ***`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`*** now it works fine... Doesn't look good though. Is there a way to make the avtivity transparent and make the snackbar work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It seems to me a snackbar in a transparent activity ought to be a notification with no activity....

Comment: @Dunoo of how the snackbar looks

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori http://imgur.com/14ykgy7 if this is what you're asking for.

Comment: so is your problem to you snackbar looking bad or activity being not transparent?

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori Activity not being transparent. When I set the theme to transparent, it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just change your `Theme` to `Theme.AppCompat` and it looks darker.

Refer that `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` to this in your `Manifest`:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

So, do your stuffs in `values -> Styles.xml`.

Here is the `Styles` after that changes, you can customize that activity here too:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>

</resources>
```

And about that Transparent, like i said you should use something like these stuffs:

in your `Layout`:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or:

[**How to create Transparent Activity in Android?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: Awesome man ! Did the trick ^^

Answer (score 1):

Go to your activity xml file and set the background to transparent

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```